# Integrate Tfs Service Hook with Jeknins: Pass branch name dynamically to Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am trying to compile code in Jenkins, when pushing code to TFS, and 
passing the branch name dynamically.

I am using the TFS Hook, and i couldn't find how to pass the branch name 
though the http Get call to Jenkins.

Any idea how to make it happen ?

thanks,
Eran.

[image]
Above is the TFS Service Hook, where i am trying to pass the branch name dynamically to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to pass the branch name in TFS  dynamically. When you set the **Trigger** of the event type--code pushed, there will be filters of branch. You have to select the branch here.

**Branch:** The branch that code was pushed into

[image]

If you want the branch in TFS repo to be dynamically pushed,  you could set the branch value= **any** as a workaround.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But this way i can trigger only one build in the tfs --> master. If i set the branch value as "any", i will not be able to determine which branch was changed, in order to build it.

Comment: Hi @eran,  Sorry, not sure what's your really requirement, if you have selected master of branch in filters , it's actually hardcode the branch name master. Then why you need to pass branch name dynamically to Jenkins Job?

Comment: Hi @eran , any update on this issue? Did my reply helped or give a right direction?